# Google Play won't show applications in android jelly bean 4.1 tablet

Tags: android, google-play

I using Jellybean 4.1 videocon vt75c tablet.  In the tablet i searched for an application using google play app.  I can't find the application.  But i find the application using website of google play using same tablet.  What is the problem ? Is it related to jellybean or the application.

advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a factory reset.  Now it works